# Decoding and accessing a json dictionary array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have the following json file which I'm sending through my mobile application to PHP and on the PHP side I want to Decode it and insert it into a mysql database.

```
 [{"Address":"Somewhere ",
    "Area":"Somwhe",
    "CreatedBy":null,
    "CreatedDate":"\/Date(1419786831365+0530)\/",
    "Distance":0,
    "EditedDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000+0000)\/",
    "Latitude":12.903999947011471,
    "Longitude":77.607999974861741,
    "Phone1":"80372899",
    "Phone2":"993729927",
    "Response":null,
    "StoreDescriptions":[],
    "StoreName":"First"},
    {"Address":"Addwmsj",
    "Area":"Sbnns",
    "CreatedBy":null,
    "CreatedDate":"\/Date(1419786863657+0530)\/",
    "Distance":0,
    "EditedDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000+0000)\/",
    "Latitude":12.960867136716843,
    "Longitude":77.647689711302519,
    "Phone1":"799268299",
    "Phone2":"68393973738",
    "Response":"Waiting",
    "StoreDescriptions":[{"LongNBQuantity":862,
                            "MeetDate":"\/Date(1419786915048+0530)\/",
                            "MeetSummary":"Meeting",
                            "Response":"Negative",
                            "StoreName":"Ssxond",
                            "id":1
                            },
                            {"LongNBQuantity":8862,
                            "MeetDate":"\/Date(1419786927673+0530)\/",
                            "MeetSummary":"Pjsjsbsj",
                            "Response":"Waiting",
                            "StoreName":"Ssxond",
                            "id":2}],
                            "StoreName":"Ssxond"},
    {"Address":"Sumwhere",
    "Area":"Righthere",
    "CreatedBy":null,
    "CreatedDate":"\/Date(1419953186686+0530)\/",
    "Distance":0,
    "EditedDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000+0000)\/",
    "Latitude":12.903999947011471,
    "Longitude":77.607999974861741,
    "Phone1":"872737288",
    "Phone2":"663838828",
    "Response":null,
    "StoreDescriptions":[],
    "StoreName":"NewEntry"}]
```

As we can see in this I have Array of objects [{},{},{}...{}] and the complexity increases when one of these objects have array of objects like {"abc":"bcd","storedesc":[{},{},{},....{}]} , so this is a little complex when compared to the simple jsons.

My code is not working. Can anybody guide me in the right direction. Thanks

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$result = json_decode($json,true);
/*
 Database connection setup done here.
*/

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    if($value){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO StoreInfo(name,created_date,edited_date,address,area,ph_num1,ph_num2,response,latitude,longitude) VALUES ($value->StoreName,$value->CreatedDate,'hellyeah',$value->Address,$value->Area,$value->Phone1,$value->Phone2,$value->Response,$value->Longitude,$value->Latitude)";
        if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
            echo "New record inserted";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Consider using prepared statements for your SQL and 2) because your JSON has nested structures, you'll need multiple database tables with some sort of join key.

Comment: What is "not working"?  What does that mean?  "Not working" doesn't have *any* meaning.  Do you see any errors?  Are any records inserted into the database?  Did your computer suddenly crash?  Anyway, let's try some *debugging*.  Did you try to `echo $sql` to see what the query you are trying to run is?  Also, don't just *assume* the query worked.  Use error checking!  Add `else{ die($conn->error); }`.

Comment: @Mr.Llama I am using 3 tables but first I wanted to insert it into 1 table.

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of reasons, this not works.

- Because you are using the `true` flag, when you are decoding the JSON, you will get back only arrays, and as I see, you want to use objects in your querys.
- In your query do not wrap your wariables with quotes.

So it will be something like this, but please, see my **NOTE** section!

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO StoreInfo (name,created_date,edited_date,address,area,
        ph_num1,ph_num2,response,latitude,longitude) 
        VALUES ('".$value["StoreName"]."','".$value["CreatedDate"]."','hellyeah',
        '".$value["Address"]."','".$value["Area"]."','".$value["Phone1"]."',
        '".$value["Phone2"]."'
        ,'".$value["Response"]."','".$value["Longitude"]."','".$value["Latitude"]."')";
```

**NOTE**

- Please escape your variables comes from outside, or use prepared statements to avoid sql injection!

Comment: due of that many columns, using prepared statements would lead to a cleaner code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

By `$result = json_decode($json,true);` it is converted to array. `true` parameter in `json_decode()` convert `JSON` to `array()`. So you should access value by `$value['CreatedDate']` instead of `$value->CreatedDate` and so on.

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    if($value){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO StoreInfo(name,created_date,edited_date,address,area,ph_num1,ph_num2,response,latitude,longitude) VALUES ('".$value['StoreName']."','".$value['CreatedDate']."','hellyeah','".$value['Address']."','".$value['Area']."','".$value['Phone1']."','".$value['Phone2']."','".$value['Response']."','".$value['Longitude']."','".$value['Latitude']."')";
        if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
            echo "New record inserted";
        }
    }
}
```

**Reference:**

- [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: You forgot to add the quotes around the values in the query.